# XPath Expression with functions

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xmldocument

I am trying to construct a XPath Expression to obtain the **prices** of all the **albums**, which were published at least 5 years ago. The XML document has the following structure:

```
<catalogue>
    <album>
        <year>1990</year>
        <price>7.99</price>
        ...
    </album>
</catalogue>
```

I tried with the following, but obviously, it has a problem:

```
string xPathExpression = "album[year<year-from-date(current-date())-5]/price";
```

This does not work either:

```
string xPathExpression = "album[year<year-from-date("2010-07-07")]/price";
```

It may be some namespace related issue or something. I found the following example, which I am not exactly sure how to implement on practice:

`year-from-date(xs:date("2005-04-23"))`

I am using C#, and more specifically `XmlDocument(SelectNodes())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`year-from-date()` and `current-date()` are XPath 2.0 functions. .NET's built-in XML libraries, including `XmlDocument`, only support XPath 1.0.

In the case of `year-from-date()`, you can just use `substring()`:

```
album[year < substring("2010-07-07", 1, 4)]/price
```

If you need a function that returns the current date, you can create a [custom function resolver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd567715(v=vs.110).aspx). This is a bit of a hassle to set up, but it will allow you to define XPath functions that do pretty much anything.

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate. Thank you for the fast response.